# Arithmetic mean - geometric mean

Tags: calculus, optimization, area, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Use arithmetic mean -geometric mean inequality to prove that perimeter of a rectangle is minimum with a given area if it is a square

Comment: That pretty much **is** the AM/GM inequality (for two variables).

Comment: I don't see a question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ and $b$ be two adjacent sides, $P$ be the perimeter and $S$ be an area of 
 the rectangle.

Thus, by AM-GM $$P=2(a+b)=4\cdot\frac{a+b}{2}\geq4\sqrt{ab}=4\sqrt{S}.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b$, id est, when our rectangle is a square.